# html anchor to jump to bottom or top of screen, depending on where you are

Tags: html, angular, anchor

I have a very long page in HTML, using Angular.
The page is divided into 2 main sections.

In the bottom of the page, I have a help bar and I want to add a button there to jump to the other section, depending on where you are. The page looks like this:

```
(a)
<div> first long list</div>
(b)
<div> second long list </div>
```

If I'm in the top of the page and I click on the button, I wish it will jump to (b) and show me the second list.
If I am watching the second list, I want the button to take me to the head of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `npm` package to manage your `anchors` `ng2-scroll-to` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-scroll-to